# how to set different x&y label in levelplot?

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I am using levelplot to plot a matrix. I need to change x and y labels. When I use the following piece of code, plot looks nice. However x and y labels are from 133 to 139 as opposed to 133..139 133...139. Can anyone help me fix it?
(instead of huge matrix i am plotting, I ll give a sample matrix)

```
library(lattice)
library(RColorBrewer)
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,2,0,2,1,1,0),6,6)
b <- c(seq(133,139),seq(133,139))
xy.labels <- b
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Spectral"))    
print(levelplot(m, scales = list(labels = xy.labels), col.regions = cols))
```

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "133 to 139" versus "133..139 133...139". On my plot, I see the numbers 134 through 139 on each of the two axes. Perhaps I'm missing code or a library?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry! What i gave as an example works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply use the `xlab` and `ylab` options.

```
print(levelplot(m, scales = list(labels = xy.labels), col.regions = cols,
            xlab='X Label', ylab='Y Label'))
```

The other labels could be changed as follows

```
B= c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
XY.labels=B
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Spectral"))    
print(levelplot(m, scales = list(labels = XY.labels), col.regions = cols,
            xlab='X Label', ylab='Y Label'))
```