# How to adjust x and y lablels in levelplot?

Tags: r, plot, axis, levelplot

Here I got the example ([how to set different x&y label in levelplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239886/how-to-set-different-xy-label-in-levelplot)) but I want more adjustment in both axis:

```
library(lattice)
library(RColorBrewer)
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,2,0,2,1,1,0),6,6)
B= c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
XY.labels=B
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Spectral"))    
print(levelplot(m, scales = list(labels = XY.labels), col.regions = cols,
        xlab='X Label', ylab='Y Label'))
```

Here it does not matter wheather you cahnge

```
B= c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
```

OR

```
B= c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')
```

So I want to change labels of both axis like:

```
B= c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h','i','j','k','l','m','n)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for:

```
library(lattice)
library(RColorBrewer)
m <- matrix(c(0,1,1,2,0,2,1,1,0),6,6)
cols <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(6, "Spectral"))    
levelplot(m, 
      scales=list(
        x=list(at=1:6,labels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")),
        y=list(at=1:6,labels=c("G","H","I","J","K","L"))
        ),
      col.regions = cols,
      xlab='X Label', ylab='Y Label')
```

[clickForResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYy0.png)

You need to add a list for each axis. Then assign labels as before. With the additional 'at' you overcome the problem starting the labels at 0.